# 404 errors when including html file with php

Tags: php, html

This php code displays a different website content, if the user is authenticated:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["authenticated"])){
    if ($_SESSION["authenticated"]) {
        include("seperatedProject/file.html");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

seperatedProject folder contains project that was developed, well, seperately with it's own css, assets,scripts..

It seems that paths in file.html, gets interpreted as originating from the document root, instead of relative to seperatedProject folder.

Example of path that isn't found with include option, but works if run separately:

```
<script src="js/design.js"></script> //404 error here
```

If i rename it to:

```
<script src="seperatedFolder/js/design.js"></script> //200 OK
```

I could rename all paths to contain the right path from php's include perspective, but is there a better way to handle this problem? Does php have an option to interpret paths relative?

UPDATE:

`/folder/fileA` contains a script link `<script src="js/design.js"></script>`

in that folder is anoher folder js, that contains `design.js`

```
/index.php contains line include("folder/fileA.html");
```

`index.php` sees `<script src="js/design.js"></script>`, because it included it. It tries searcing for `js/design.js`.. but it does not know it must search in  `/folder/js,` because it sees paths from it's own perspective. Hope that makes my problem clearer

Comment: Starting the `src`/`href` with a `/` will always have it start at the webroot.

Comment: yeah, that is why I didn't not start it with a forward slash

Comment: What do you mean? With the `/` it would always point to the right location? The `include` is failing or the javascript/CSS calls from the included script?

Comment: When project in seperatedFolder was developed..its root was seperatedfolder. Now that folder was copied into another folder and what previously meant / for seperatedFolder, now changed meaning. I can always rewrite eveything to absolute paths, but was hoping for a solution not to do that.

Comment: *"It seems that paths in `file.html`"* - That's unclear for me as far as the PHP-related goes.

Comment: `include("/var/user/public/seperatedProject/file.html");` - Keep it simple and use a full system path when referencing files outside of the root. Do the same thing for anything else.

Comment: The server is instructed correctly with the rewrites. I am not injecting JS, I am injecting <script> tag. I added some more explanations of the problem.

Comment: That is always an option. I was hoping for a php feature, that keeps paths in the correct perspective.